# Cursor hidden when editing text in TextInputEditText once keyboard is up

Tags: android

I have a simple layout with two `TextInputEditText` fields below each other within a `NestedScrollView`:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

  <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext_verses"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:gravity="top|start"
                android:minLines="10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext_experience"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:minLines="10"
                android:gravity="top|start"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
  </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` for the corresponding activity in the manifest.

I have lots of text in the first `TextInputEditText`. When the user wants to edit the text at the beginning by touching it, the keyboard come up but text view suddenly jumps up and the cursor hides behind the top. So the user must edit the text "blindly" because the cursor is gone.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is a [reported bug](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1282).

My solution was to switch back to the regular `EditText`.